# Android: Set the width of an ImageView to be X% of it's parent with RemoteViews

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 `ImageView` elements that look like this:

```html
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/progressBarBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/progress_bar_shape"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/progressBarFill"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/progress_bar_shape"
        />
```

**My goal** is to mimick a progress bar using 2 images layed on top of each other, by resizing the `progressBarFill`

**My question** is how can I resize the width of `progressBarFill` so that it's X% of it's parent's width?

Thank you!